# Betweenness centrality - between two groups

Tags: graph-theory, networks

I'm familiar with metrics of node centrality in a network. In particular betweenness centrality. Is there a metric that measures the betweenness of a node, for being in between 2 or more, pre-determined, groups?

Comment: Welcome to Cross-Validated and thank you for your question. Are you specifically interested in published measures or would you be happy with some impromptu translation of he betweenness to your task? Also, you may want to take a look at [this proposal for a new site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104390).

Comment: Well, since you ask. ideally I'd like something in the igraph package in R! (I can't find it)
I can think of a few heuristic measures myself, but I wonder if there is something more formal and established.

Comment: You might want to check the [periodic table of network centrality](http://schochastics.net/sna/periodic.html)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure I found what I wanted yet, but this was useful.

Comment: Yes. Betweenness is defined in terms of all-pair shortest paths. Instead, you may use shortest paths that start in group A and end in group B. This is now implemented in the igraph C core as "subset betweenness", it will be in the next python-igraph release, and it will eventually reach the R interface as well.